# Windows 10 Search to list every instance of search text

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-search

I've gotten the Windows search tool to work to find when various files contain a certain text (in this case, a server name).

The list of results shows me each file.  However, I know there are multiple instances of the server name in some of these files.

Is there a way to get this tool to list separate lines for each occurrence, even if it won't indicate the line position for each?

Ah, to muddy the waters, I am searching on a shared location (e.g. \\netdrive\subfolder\..)

Keith's suggestion looks good, but I am unsure I can drive Powershell to that location remotely.

Comment: You're better off using Notepad++ find in files for this, and then bookmark the result set.

Comment: Make sure in the Indexing setup where you pick file types to be indexed, that you also select Content where appropriate (Office files for example and Adobe) and then rebuild the index. I see all the content in the files I find.

Comment: @KeithMiller This looks like what I need.  Cook one up and the cred is yours.

Comment: Ah, Keith, wait.  Maybe I should have added to the conditions here

Comment: Cool. Edit your question with relevant specifics. I'll compose the answer this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have the opportunity to test with actual network locations, **PowerShell** plays well with UNC paths, and my testing local folders refenced by a UNC path, i.e.
`\\<ComputerName>\Users\<UserProfileFolder>\Documents`
worked fine. So as long as you have access to the folders/files in question, I don't think the network location wll be an issue.

---

### This should do the trick. Detailed explanation follows:

1. Execute your desired search in **File Explorer**
2. *With the **Search Results** window remaining open*, execute the following code, substituting your server name (or other desierd search text) in the `$SearchText` variable asignmennt:

   ```
   $SearchText   = 'ServerName' ### replace ServerName with the content you're searching for
   $Shell        = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
   $SearchWindow = @($Shell.Windows()) | ? { $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like 'Search Results*' }
   $FilePaths    = @($SearchWindow.Document.Folder.Items()).Path
   Select-string -Path $FilePaths -Pattern $SearchText | select LineNumber, Path
   ```

---

**PowerShell** alone is unaware of the [Shell namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro#:%7E:text=The%20Shell%20namespace%20organizes%20the,version%20of%20the%20file%20system.) and virtual folderfs such as **This PC**, **Libraries**, and t**Search Results**. But we can create an instace of The [shell.application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) COM object that allows us to bridge that gap. Creating an instance in **PowerShell** looks like this:

- `$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application`

**PowerShell** is object-oriented, so you can examine any objects properties and methods by piping it to [Get-Member](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.2) (aliased as `gm`), i.e. `$Shell | gm`. It's a great way to explore and learn.

The [Windows()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windows) metod returns another COM object, [ShellWindows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellwindows), which represents a collection of the currently open **File Explorer** and **Internet Explorer** windows. Enumerating these collections with their native methods is tricky, but fortunately PowerShell will enumerate the collection if you wrap in an [array operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--), `@($Shell.Winndows())`. Then we have a collection open windows. Even with multiple Explorer windnows open, assuming you only have one with search results, it's easy enough to find by examininng the underlying [FolderItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem)'s path property:

```
$SearchWindow = @($Shell.Windows()) | Where-Object { $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like 'Search Results*' }
```

- If you only have one **Explorer** window open, you can eliminate the `Where-Object filter
  $SearchWindow = @($Shell.Windows())

with that window, we use the associated [Folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder) object's [Itmes()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-items) method to get the [FolderItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem)s that correspond the the files in your search results. Because [Items()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-items) returns another COM collection object, we use the [array operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) again:

- `@($SearchWindow.Document.Folder.Items())`

and then use the [member access operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#member-access-operator-) (`.`) to obtain an array of paths:

- `@($SearchWindow.Document.Folder.Items()).Path`

This should list all the file paths

The [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlet is a powerful tool for searching text files:

> The Select-String cmdlet uses regular expression matching to search for text patterns in input strings and files. You can use Select-String similar to grep in UNIX or findstr.exe in Windows.

For your purposes, use the `-Path` parameter to specify the paths to the files and the `-Pattern` parameter to specify the text you're looking for. The default return for each match found is somewhat wordy:

```
\\JP\Users\keith\Documents\web\Recipes\Meatloaf --    Uncorrected OCR.txt:22:hour. This
loaf should be basted everj, ts minutes. This is an excelleni;;.tioli
```

But the returned object is a [MatchInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) object with all these properties:

```
PS C:\>Select-string -Path (@($SearchWindow.Document.Folder.Items()).Path[1..5]) -Pattern 'x' | gm -MemberType Properties


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name       MemberType Definition
----       ---------- ----------
Context    Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename   Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line       Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches    Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path       Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern    Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

So `LineNumber` and `Path` are probalby good choices:

```
Select-string -Path (@($SearchWindow.Document.Folder.Items()).Path) -Pattern 'ServerName' | select LineNumber, Path
```

So, a lot of explantion (Teach a man to fish...), but pretty concise in the end:

1. Execute your desired search in **File Explorer**
2. *With the **Search Results** window remaining open*, execute the following code, substituting your server name (or other desierd search text) in the `$SearchText` variable asignmennt:

   ```
   $SearchText   = 'ServerName'
   $SearchText   = [Regex]::Escape('ServerName')
   $Shell        = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
   $SearchWindow = @($Shell.Windows()) | ? { $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like 'Search Results*' }
   $FilePaths    = @($SearchWindow.Document.Folder.Items()).Path
   Select-string -Path $FilePaths -Pattern $SearchText | select LineNumber, Path
   ```

The above uses intermediate variables for clarity, but it's always better to keep things moving through the pipeline and keep literals out of code. So this is probalby better:

```
$SearchText   = ''ServerName'
$WinCriteria  = { $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like 'Search Results*' }
$Shell        = New-Object -ComObject shell.application

@($Shell.Windows()) | where $WinCriteria | ForEach-Object {
    @($_.Document.Folder.Items()).Path | Get-Item | Select-String $SearchText | select LineNumber, Path
}
```

If the only **Explorer window** open is the `Search Results...` window, you can simplify to:

```
@(@($Shell.Windows()).Document.Folder.Items()).Path | Get-Item | select-string $SearchText |select LineNumber , Path
```

If your searh text contains any characters with special meaning to regular exparessions,use the `[Regex]::Escape()` method:

```
@(@($Shell.Windows()).Document.Folder.Items()).Path | Get-Item | select-string [Regex]::Escape($SearchText) |select LineNumber , Path
```

And you might want to groip by Path and dispaly all the line numbers for that path:

```
@(@($Shell.Windows()).Document.Folder.Items()).Path | Get-Item | select-string [Regex]::Escape($SearchText) |select LineNumber , Path | group Path | select Name , @{ n = 'Line #' ; E = {$_.Group.LineNumber -join ', ' }}
```

Comment: Looks great.  Let me test this today and I will get back to you.

Comment: A couple of things: I have run these commands accessing the search remotely.  When I execute the third command, nothing happens.  Should I be piping results somewhere?

Also, I do have access to the remote box.  But it is a production box, and I don't want to alter the Folder View options so I can search on these file types.

Comment: As I said, I haven't had to opportunity to gain experience in a network environment and I don't have experience with remote access. Also, I just edited my answer somewhat, so not sure of what you're calling the third command. Is the File Explorer search running onn your computer or a remote computer? What Folder View options do you feel you have to modify?

Comment: You might add `PowerShell` and whatever tag is a ppropriate to remoting to gain the input of those more versed in these areas...

Comment: I tried your updated commands, each set.  They execute without error, but don't affect anything.  The file explorer is running on my machine, I am accessing the remote server in that file explorer.  The folder view options I would have to change on the prod box (which I have successfully changed here), is enabling .config and .cmd extensions for plaintext searching and updating the indexes.  I did that on my machine yesterday and it took hours.  It may not affect anything, but I don't want to mess with prod.

Comment: OK. Let's break it down. Does `$Shell<Enter>` show that it's a com object? Does `$Shell.Windows()` return info about open winndows? Can you isolate the `$SearchREsults window?

Comment: $Shell <enter> returns the expected.  $Shell.Windows() returns info on about the one currently open (the location name is the search text, the URL is empty).  When I type $SearchResults <enter>, nothing happens

Comment: Did you define `$SearchResults`? I defined `$SearchWindow`... Test the expression: `@($Shell.Windows()) | ? { $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like 'Search Results*' }`

Comment: But I've also found we can't pass paths via the pipelinne as strinngs, only `[IO.FileInfo]`objects. But the array of paths should work when specified as the `-Path` parameter.

Comment: If you only have the one window open, this should return all the file paths: `@(@($Shell.Windows()).Document.Folder.Items()).Path`.  Does it? If so, then try this: `@(@($Shell.Windows()).Document.Folder.Items()).Path | gi | select-string 'ServerName' |select LineNumber , Path`  --- making sure to replace `ServerName` with the actual text you're searchignn for.

Comment: Bingo.  That worked.  I am unsure why the variables didn't carry over to work otherwise...and maybe it's because I had multiple explorer window open earlier.

Please incorporate this last comment and the cred is yours.